# What happens behind the scenes when we marshal string variable within a struct?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

I'd like to pass the struct containing string fields allocated by the managed code to the unmanaged code, write data to the string fields and return the struct back to the C# application.

Unfortunately I can't go with StringBuilder since it's not possible to marshal a struct containg a StringBuilder field.

Here is the quick solution I came up with:

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CustomerData 
{
    public string firstName;   
    public string lastName;  
    ...
    //other-fields
}

[DllImport("test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern public static void Modify(ref CustomerData data);
```

Here is the calling code:

```
CustomerData data = new CustomerData();
data.firstName = new String('\0', 50);
data.lastName = new String('\0', 50);

Modify(ref data);
```

C++:

```
class CustomerData
{
public:
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
};

extern "C"
void __declspec(dllexport) Modify(CustomerData* data)
{
    strncpy_s(data->firstName, 50, "John", 50);
    strncpy_s(data->lastName, 50, "Doe", 50);
}
```

I'm quite concerned about this approach because of at least two reasons:

- I'm not sure that buffer passed to the C++ code won't be overflowed.
- I don't understand what happens behind the scenes and how string variable is marshalled to char* variable and back and what drawbacks it might contain.

Could you explain what happens behind the scenes when we marshal string variable within a struct?

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but what is the size of the string buffer being marshalled?

Comment: And how does it actually work? Does it copy the content of the string buffer into new buffer which is passed to the c++ method? And does it copy it back to the original string when returning from the function? Are there any way to see how the internals work?